# modeling screw plastic cover for 3d printing

Tags: modeling

Hello I have been using blender for a little while now and while I am quite confident at modeling "normal" objects I am now stuck at the right way to model a plastic cover for assembly screws that is shaped like an angled screw cap. But pictures are surely more explicative than my words (see below). what's the best way to approach this modeling?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have modeled this "solid" and whitout the little hinges on the sides. but is it the right way to go? and how do you extract "the skin" out of the solid i built ?

Comment: please show your current result also...

Answer (score -2):

If you have already modeled the solid piece, maybe you could delete the faces you don't need (on the second photo the face "under" and "right side" ) and use the "SOLIDIFY" modifier ? find the good value for thickness, apply the modifier. Then you can add the hinges by extruding some faces.
If this can help ?